# Change TextView and save on SharedPreferences

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences

I have a TextView that holds a text and I want to change it on button click and save it on sharedpreferences untill the app is restarted then it goes back to its default text.

here is my code:

```
TextView questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.perso);
questionText.setText("Default text");
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetConsent();
            questionText.setText("You clicked on the button");


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the sample code,

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG =MainActivity.class.getSimpleName() ;
    private  TextView questionText ;
    private   Button button ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(TAG,"onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        questionText = findViewById(R.id.perso);
        questionText.setText("Default text");
        //Setting curent text into the shared preferance
        setSharedpreferance("ButtonText1",questionText.getText().toString());
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                questionText.setText("You clicked on the button");
                setSharedpreferance("ButtonText1",questionText.getText().toString());
                Log.v(TAG,"Sharedpref value"+getSharedpreferance("ButtonText1"));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        Log.v(TAG,"onResume");
        questionText.setText(getSharedpreferance("ButtonText1"));
    }

    private void setSharedpreferance(String key, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);  // Saving string
        // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
        editor.apply();
    }

    private  String getSharedpreferance(String key){
        //To get the sharedpreferance value
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return pref.getString(key, null);
    }
}
```

You should need to look on the android activity lifecycle 
 when a new activity creates it will invoke the following if the OnResume() is available in the Activity class.
Oncreate-> OnResume

Comment: thank you when i jump between activities the text go back to the original text, it doesnt get stored untill i restart the app

Comment: works good, just the onResume part deletes the default text of the oncreate on first time i open the activity

Comment: @LoveDroid Yes, it removes the default text and assigns the string from the shared preference.if the answer is work for you please accept it.

Comment: How can I make the default text stays until i click on the button, because on first oncreate i dont see even the default text? the default text should be there until i click on the button

Comment: @LoveDroid check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single class extending the Application class, this will sustain the value till your app is opened and can also be accessed across different activities in your app. Same concept you can extend with the sharedPreferences if you really have the need to use it.

More about androids `Application` class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application)

```
public class Mydata extends Application {
    private static Mydata d;
    private static String textVal;
    public Mydata getInstance(){
        return d;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        d= this;
    }
}
```

On click of the button save the data in the single class.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetConsent();
            questionText.setText("You clicked on the button");
            Mydata.textVal=questionText.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

In the onCreate() method set the value in the `TextView` as:

```
  questionText.setText(Mydata.textVal);
```

You can also look into the new `LifeCycle` android library:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code it doesnt work. when i exit the activity where i want to apply that sharedpreferences to the MainActivity and I go back to that activity I find that the textview goes back to the original text. I want to keep the new text untill I restart the app not jump between activities

Comment: @LoveDroid Modified answer as you need

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code in the SharePreferences documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) u can see the code snipet for reading and writing in the link and instead of using putInt and getInt use putString, and getString you need a Key to identify the value that you just saved.